# /bin/sh: 1: gcloud: not found

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have my NodeJS service running on Cloud App Engine. From this NodeJS service, I want to execute gcloud command. I am getting the below error and my app engine NodeJS service failed to run the gcloud command.

/bin/sh: 1: gcloud: not found

Comment: standard or flex environment?

Comment: flex environment. Do we need to set some environment in app.yaml file of my service for gcloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Connect to your instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/debugging-an-instance#connecting_to_the_instance) and check if you have the gcloud SDK installed in the default runtime image supplied by Google.

If it isn't installed (not impossible - it doesn't appear included in the standard environment either, see [System Packages Included in the Node.js Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/reference/system-packages)) then you could try to treat it just like any other non-node.js dependency and build a custom runtime with it - see [Google App Engine - specify custom build dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51353656/google-app-engine-specify-custom-build-dependencies/51353866#51353866)

If it is installed check if you need to tweak your app's environment to access it.

But in general the `gcloud` command isn't really designed to be executed on the deployed instances. Depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve, there may be better suited/more direct/programmatic API alternatives (which, probably in most cases, is what the `gcloud` command invokes under the hood as well).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped me to find the problem. Is there a way that we can update the docker file for the default nodejs runtime image to add this non-nodejs additional dependencies for gcloud sdk?

Comment: Not the default image - that's under Google control. That's exactly where the custom runtime I mentioned comes into play.